# Set Cookie & Maintain While Browsing - Cloudflare Worker

Tags: javascript, cookies, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am attempting to set a cookie and maintain this cookie while browsing using Cloudflare Workers. Right now I am struggling in two areas:

1.) Custom Expiration Date to Set Time: 1 Day, 1 Week, etc. (I cannot find documentation on this anywhere)

2.) Cookie Disappears when changing URL from the single URL worker is set to run on.

Current Code:

```
// Fetch the request and pass it through the function
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(fetchAndApply(event.request))
})

async function fetchAndApply(request) {
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
let response = await fetch(request);
response = new Response(response.body, response);

response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "4pricing-mode=on; Expires='${date}'; Path='/';");

return response;
}
```

**Note, I was able to fix 2.) by correcting the "Path" inside of my cookie to this:**

```
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "6pricing-mode=on; Expires='${date}';Path=/");
```

I still cannot figure out how to set dynamic expiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Instead of using Expire, I simply used max-age; which defines the amount of seconds to keep the cookie alive - I have set mine at 7 days

2.) I removed the apostrophe's around /, which now allows the cookie to pass to alternative urls of my website:

```
response.headers.set('Set-Cookie', "pricing-mode=on;max-age=604800;Path=/");
```